# Windows Phone in-app purchases: Receipt validation certificate missing

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, windows-phone

We are getting HTTP 404 when trying to download the certificate for validating the receipt. I've seen two different URIs to fetch the certificate, of which the other is a redirect to the first one. Below is the supposed URI to the certificate:

[Certificate with id: A656B9B1B3AA509EEA30222E6D5E7DBDA9822DCD](https://lic.apps.microsoft.com/licensing/certificateserver/?cid=A656B9B1B3AA509EEA30222E6D5E7DBDA9822DCD)

The address should be fine as I'm able to download another certificate with a different id mentioned [here (id: b809e47cd0110a4db043b3f73e83acd917fe1336)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/bd70041b-b97b-4a93-9a7e-ca638e50e390/how-to-validate-an-inapp-purchase-receipt-on-my-server)

My guess is, that this is due to our app being a **beta** app at the moment and since I can find the same certificate id from the example receipt in this [sample here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/In-app-purchase-receipt-c3e0bce4), but haven't been able to verify it.

Edit: the in-app products are also free at the moment if that matters

Comment: I did not. We've put this on hold until we are able to get a pre-release to the actual store to finalize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, as the Beta certificate was never deployed to the server.  I have worked to get that added and now you should be able to use the sample code, as is, and download the certificate without receiving a 404.

https://lic.apps.microsoft.com/licensing/certificateserver/?cid=A656B9B1B3AA509EEA30222E6D5E7DBDA9822DCD

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally got this to work.

The link you posted with the b809.. id is for windows apps, not windows phone 8 apps. It appears the certificate is different.

The id from the test receipt you posted is the same I am getting in my beta app and I think it will be the same when we go out of beta.

Inside the example found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/In-app-purchase-receipt-c3e0bce4), in the zip file there is a file called IapReceiptProduction.cer. If you double click it and view details you will see it has a thumbprint that matches your certificate id.

I included that file in my solution and I load it using the sample code from my [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/In-app-purchase-receipt-c3e0bce4) and that works.

I just hope they wont change the certificate at some point.

EDIT: It appears the phone emulator does not get signed receipts (my working test was on an actual phone). The receipts I get in the emulator also have a different certificate id (FB3D3A6455095D2C4A841AA8B8E20661B10A6112).

Comment: could you plz tell me how to obtain IapReceiptProduction.cer file. As you said this file contain thumbprint which matches our certificate id. but the sample do not include in the project. it shows some error. could you plz tell me how to get it to work.

Comment: Click the link in my answer, and download the zip file by clicking the black button that says "C# (36.6kb)". In the zip file there is a folder named "C#", the file is in there.

Comment: There is a solution file for VS2010 in the C# folder as well. If I build the solution and go to the output directory in a CMD console, I can run the example with the command: "ConsoleVerfiySignature.exe ReceiptSHA256.xml IapReceiptProduction.cer". The cer file is also copied to the output directory on build.

Comment: But my question is how can i verify the receipt for my app. how can i include this code(zip code)in my windows phone 8 app. when I try to add the code in my app. it showing me error on referencing

Comment: How do we get the IapReceiptProduction.cer file for my app with Thumbprint value same as my certificateid.

Comment: Not sure about putting the code in the phone app. You probably need to reference the System.Security .Net component in your project. We are doing the verification on an Azure server so its not implemented in our phone app.

Comment: Not sure which certificate it is you want. If its the one with id:A656B9B1B3AA509EEA30222E6D5E7DBDA9822DCD , then its in the zip file, if its any other certificate I cant help you. I'm just hoping I will never need another .cer file.